# Setting environment variable for sudo in Yosemite

Tags: macos, terminal, launchd

I followed this similar question to set my environment variables in Yosemite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite/26179907#26179907

I want to do the same thing, but for sudo

```
do shell script "sudo launchctl setenv variablename value" with administrator privileges
```

but somehow, it does not show if I go in a terminal afterwards and run the command:

```
sudo launchctl getenv variablename
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first line of code is wrong. If you say `sudo` and `with administrator privileges` you are doing the same thing twice. If you use the terminal, as you can see, the following works:

```
$ sudo launchctl setenv TEST true
Password:<you have to insert your password here>
$ sudo launchctl getenv TEST
true
```

You could unset the variable with the command:

```
$ sudo launchctl unsetenv TEST
```

You don't need an applescript to do that.

Comment: I think I didn't mention it, but I am using apple script to load the variables at each reboot! I'll test your solution and see if it works.

Comment: Using your solution, of not saying `sudo` and adding `with administrator privileges`, with AppleScript worked! Thank you